# cmake OUTPUT_VARIABLE is not working with docker build

Tags: docker, cmake, alpine-linux

Here comes a strange issue when run docker build with cmake.

If run `cmake .` directly, it works perfect that the message shows the version get from get_version.sh like `!!!! Warning !!!! build version <1.6.3>`.

But if trying to build a image from `docker build . -t test` it only shows `!!!! Warning !!!! build version <>`.

That's quite strange! Anyone has any idea about this issue?

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN mkdir build
WORKDIR /build

RUN apk add --update build-base cmake

COPY CMakeLists.txt CMakeLists.txt
COPY get_version.sh get_version.sh
RUN cmake .
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project("testcmake")

execute_process(COMMAND chmod 777 ./get_version.sh)

execute_process(COMMAND ./get_version.sh
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE
    VERSION_INFO)
MESSAGE(STATUS "!!!! Warning !!!! build version <${VERSION_INFO}>")
```

get_version.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
retval=$(echo -ne "1.6.3")
echo -ne $retval
```

Comment: To debug this, you can expand your call to `execute_process(COMMAND ./get_version.sh OUTPUT_VARIABLE VERSION_INFO ERROR_VARIABLE ERROR_INFO)` and print `ERROR_INFO` to see if there was any issue running the script.

Comment: Just noticed your shebang is `#!/bin/bash`. Alpine doesn't have bash, at least by default, so your script I think just fails. Try with `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @KamilCuk That's the root cause!! Thank you! Either install bash or change to use sh will solve this issue.